# Find System Drive In Visual Basic 2013 & 6

Tags: visual-studio

For some of my programs i need to find system drive. I mean the drive that includes **Program Files** & **Windows** folder. 
For example : C:/Program Files -----> Drive **C** is a system drive.
When i write "%SystemDrive%" in **Windows Explorer** it will take me to the system drive.
But in **Visual Basic 2013 & 6** when i use this string in dir command , nothing happens!
By leading an example :
    Shell("%SystemDrive%/Windows/System32/Shutdown.exe -s -t 00 -----> No output.
What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You can Use the same Environment varible for these versions of Visual basic ..try accessing them using `Environ`, e.g. `Environ("SystemDrive")`.

OR

you can use the following API driven code for getting the windows Drive and then navigate as per your need.

```
Private Declare Function GetWindowsDirectory Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetWindowsDirectoryA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, ByVal nSize As Long) As Long

Private Function GetSystemDrive() As String
GetSystemDrive = Space(1000)
Call GetWindowsDirectory(GetSystemDrive, Len(GetSystemDrive))
GetSystemDrive = Left$(GetSystemDrive, 2)
 End Function

Private Sub Form_Load()
Debug.Print GetSystemDrive
End Sub
```